# Do I need to run as administrator if I use Java Preferences API?

Tags: java, preferences, administrator

I'm asking that because I really don't want to ask user every time for administrator privileges, but I want to save some settings with Java Preferences.

I want to make a trial application and store the date with Java Preferences API.

I want to know:

1. Do I need the administrator privileges if I use Java Preferences
   API?
2. If I need the administrator privileges only when I'm writing a key with Java Preferences API, can I ask user to give me the administrator privileges only when I am using the method to write a key?

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should take 5 minutes to write some code to test it out.  FWIW, I think that a user preference system that required admin rights would be next to useless ... and I can't imagine that Sun/Oracle would have done that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not required as storage is JVM-dependant. Probably preferences can be strored in user settings for Windows like plenty of applications do. 
It would be unusable if eg. on linux, to use you application you would have tu run it with root privilages.
So the answer is no, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save user-specific settings, then you won't need administrator privileges. But if you want to save system-specific settings (i.e. that are the same for all users of the application on a machine), then you definitely need administrator privileges on Windows (and probably also on other operating systems but I have not tested that yet).